# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule with coupon always fails

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I can not work out why my shopping cart price rule either always fails with Coupon code "starter001" is not valid. if these are the conditions;

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  AS042  
Quantity in cart  greater than  0  

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is one of  AS002 , AS001 , AS003 , AS004 ...  
Quantity in cart  greater than  0
```

OR

If i change this line "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: " to "If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true: " for both statements then the discount is always applied.

The discount is using a coupon code and I have attached the details of each screen setup as an image.

[image: Rule Information]

[image: Conditions]

[image: Actions]

Basically if you buy 1 or more of an item with SKU AS042 AND any product in the list of SKU's AS001 through AS040 then you get a $10.95 discount off your whole cart

Comment: The "quantity in cart greater than 0" condition is obsolete?

Comment: I've tried not having it, and having it or having it as quantity is greater than or equal to 1 - still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As I know (and tried) you can't use multiple SKUs in one condition, even with **AND**. Probably the system is checking each item separately (i.e. one by one) and conditions like `SKU = X and SKU = Y` will not work even if you have both products in your cart.

A solution could be separating the conditions:

In **Conditions** tab:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  SPROD
```

And in **Actions** tab:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
SKU  is one of  4THPROD, FPROD, TPROD, bundle1
```

This solution is a little bit *ugly* and is limited to 2 SKU conditions only but it works.

Comment: Thanks enenen, i started to try this so changed it so it had a condition of;
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
SKU  is  AS042 and no other conditions or actions and it still didn't work?

Comment: This is driving me crazy! I tried it the exact way you said with both condition and action, no luck. Then just action, still no luck. I can not work out why this won't work!

Comment: Ok I tried changing SKU  is  SPROD   to SKU contains SPROD and it works!! Could it maybe be something to do with "is"?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. In your case it would be `is AS042` in the `Conditions` tab and `is one of  AS002 , AS001 , AS003 , AS004` in the `Actions` tab. (or some other SKUs which you need). It's working on me with `is`. It will work with `contains`, too, but with similar SKUs you can have unexpected problems.

Comment: You both save my day, putting exactly 1 sku for each condition and use `contains` instead of `is` fix my problem too.

Answer (score -1):

`Uses per Customer` is 0. In my magento 1.7.0.2 it's blank, not zero by default. Maybe you can try to leave it blank?

Also your rules aren't very good. `Quantity in cart` is always greater than 0, because otherwise you can't go to the checkout in standard magento.

The first condition says, the sku have to be `AS042`, but in the second condition, the sku can also be `AS003`. So if you're only have sku `AS003` in your cart, it's not possible to use the coupon code, because you're defined that ALL(!) conditions have to be true.

Comment: You can't make uses per customer blank, it gets converted to 0 on save. 0 should mean no limit, anyway, because a coupon that cannot be used makes no sense. That's what the *Status* setting is for. Quantity in cart has to be set for a condition, because the category selection is only available from the third level.